# I want to stop the loop for my if else statement in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the code in my controller..

```
def create
@batch = Batch.find(params[:batch_id])
@exam_group = ExamGroup.find(params[:exam_group_id])
@module = StudentAdditionalField.find(params[:module_id])
@question = Question.new(params[:question])
@question.student_additional_field_id = @module.id
@question.exam_group_id = @exam_group.id
if @question.save or request.post?  
  if ( @question.id == @module.questions )
    flash[:notice] =  "Total no of questions added"
    redirect_to batch_exam_group_module_questions_path(@batch, @exam_group, @module), :id => @question_id
  else
    flash[:notice] =  "Question Added"
    redirect_to new_batch_exam_group_module_question_path(@batch, @exam_group, @module)
  end
end
```

end

and my sql for modules is

```
+----+--------+-----------+-------+

| id | name   | questions | marks |
+----+--------+-----------+-------+
|  1 | Quants | 1         | 1     |
|  2 | Eng    | 2         | 2     |
|  3 | Reason | 3         | 3     |
+----+--------+-----------+-------+
```

here the if statement doesn't get only else statement works

Comment: So a module has many questions I assume. The if statement is probably executing because there are no questions for that module and becuase @question is a new object its id is nil. so nil == nil being true the if part always executes.

Comment: Also your @question.id might always be nil if question.save returns false and the request is post

Comment: I think you need to reduce params, queries, instance variables, dependencies and route nestings at first. I don't know your business logic but they seem too much.

Answer (score 0):

@module.questions will return a array on all questions related to the module. This should work

```
if ( @question.id == @module.questions.last.id )
```

Comment: This may throw an error is the request is a post request and @module.questions is an empty array.

Comment: No, it will not, if question is saved properly

Comment: and if @question.save returns false because of some validations or any other cause and the request is a post request it will throw an error.

Comment: Yeah I said if "properly". There is no need for request.post? I understood your point earlier.

Comment: instead of @module.questions i use '1 or 2' numbers manually it works

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are trying to check the question is in particular module or not.
  You may try

```
if @module.questions.include?(@question)
```

I was wondering, you may not need to test the type of the request, because if you follow the default rails resources structure, create action will always receive 'post' request only.

Update:

I think the association between Module and Question is like

```
class StudentAdditionalField
  has_many :questions
end

class Question
  belongs_to :StudentAdditionalField
end
```

You are manually associating the question to the module.

```
@module   = StudentAdditionalField.find(params[:module_id])
@question = Question.new(params[:question])
@question.student_additional_field_id = @module.id
# ...
@question.save
```

So there will be no such condition, when question will not be associated with the module, so the else part will never be executed.

There is one way if params[:question] contains information about the module, then you should not set the student_additional_field_id manually. Then it will work fine.

I think you want to send the module info from the UI as 
    params[:question][:student_additional_field_id]

See if makes sense.

Comment: instead of @module.questions i use '1 or 2' numbers manually it works

Comment: @RajaSekar Are you not making it really really static then ?

Comment: @RajaSekar Not sure what you want to do ... If you really want to check, the question you added is the last question in the module, you can try `if @module.questions.include?(@question) && @question == @module.questions.last`